# Issue while working with Module Design Pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I wanted to use Module Design pattern in my javascript code, but i am facing weird issue while running the code. It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

One more question i wanted to ask is is it proper way to write module pattern design ? I am trying to call methods of other objects is it fine to do this way ?

Below is my JS code.

**JS Code**

```
var importedArray = [];
var offlineTask = (function(importedArray){
 return {
    processOfflineConsolidation :function(){
      if(importedArray){ 
         if(true){
          QSTMRow.mergeQuestion();
        }else{
        alert('you cannot import data from another Visit\'s assignment');
        }
      }else{
        alert('Imported Array is not accessible or it is null');
      }
    }
  };
})(importedArray);

var QSTMRow = (function(){
        mergeQuestion : function(){      
          /*mergeScore('F.QST_COMP_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_MGMT_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_IMPL_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP1',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP2',1);*/
        },

    return {
      mergeQuestion : mergeQuestion
    };
})();


offlineTask.processOfflineConsolidation();
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo6sc39x/)

Comment: `mergeQuestion : function(){` - this syntax is invalid (`mergeQuestion` is treated as a label here).

Comment: @SharathBangera I think you're being downvoted because your code has a syntax error that will look obvious to many readers. I tried to answer that, assuming you're still new to JS. That being said, you're right to ask for more details about downvotes, but the last part of your comment is just of show of anger - you can do without it. Cheers.

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down vote

Comment: thanks everyone. Can any tell me whether this is the right way to do it ? or is there any other way to write the same code ?

Comment: @phtrivier how does syntax error lead to negative point? I dint know what was wrong that is why i posted it. if i knew why i would i post it in stack overflow.

Comment: @SharathBangera StackOverflow should not be mistaken for a syntax checker (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252256/behavior-on-questions-caused-by-typographical-errors for the discussion). I agree that it's a bit blunt to downvote without explanation, but it's generally agreed that you should deal with very obvious errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError" by yourself before posting - or make it clear that you're new to the language and don't know how to deal with that yet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned, the syntax is invalid for the second module ; you probably want

```
var QSTMRow = (function(){
   return {
        mergeQuestion : function(){      
          /*mergeScore('F.QST_COMP_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_MGMT_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_IMPL_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP1',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP2',1);*/
        }
   };
})();
```

or

```
var QSTMRow = (function(){
     var mergeQuestion = function(){      
          /*mergeScore('F.QST_COMP_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_MGMT_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_IMPL_SCORE',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP1',1);
          mergeScore('F.QST_ADDITIONAL_RESP2',1);*/
     };

    return {
      mergeQuestion : mergeQuestion
    };
})();
```